# Leanback library support for API level 19 Android for TV app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, leanback

Is there a Leanback library support for API level 19 of Android? In this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/package-summary.html Google says it supports API level 21+. So I am not sure if there's a support for API level 19.

Comment: I have tested it on my Android 4.4.2 STB, the [Leanback](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) running fine.

Comment: I'm not sure where it says that. I think that since it is v17.Leanback, it should work all the way down to API level 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LeanBack was introduced in the support library `v21` so no it is not in v19

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v17-leanback

if you are asking if you can use this in android version 19 aka 4.4 yes just use support library v21

Comment: Thanks for answer but if i want to use leanback in kitkat, is that possible to use it in kitkat ?

Comment: yes, but that would be forcing teh library to run which may produce some unwanted UI Glitches.