# android studio run button doesnt do anything

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I had my project running. And testing it on mobile device by clicking on the run button. But suddenly it has stopped working. Whenever i click on run button (run configuration is selected) it opens the dialog to choose the device but afterwards it does nothing. 
Please help me with this problem. Since it has wasted my whole time.

Comment: anything in the gradle logs ?

Comment: restart the studio and check

Comment: no, gradle logs show absolutely nothing. and yes i have tries restarting android studio. (plus, have also tried invalidating cache and restarting)

Comment: maybe reinstall the studio ? which version are you using

Comment: im using 2.0, by the way it has been working fine since a pretty good period of time. as long ago as 4 hours. it was working perfectly well.

Comment: there is only one project or more than  one in ur studio..pls check u have selected proper project in ur studio..i mean in left side of ur run button...

Comment: well, there are 2 modules one is for mobile and one for TV i have selected mobile module run configuration , that is showing on the left side of the run button currently.

Comment: did u try uninstall the apk from ur device and reconnect and run...? if not try dat also...in case it doesnt sove as @Shubhank saying reinstall the studio...

Comment: Ok, in any case thanks.. Will do uninstall the apk and if it does not work will reinstall studio, seems im out of options

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Studio project was working fine. After updateding the gradle plugin, it started showing the same issue. 
Updating the Android studio to latest version only solved the problem. Looks like compatibility issue

Answer (score 0):

@ShoaibAnwar Firstly Android Studio 2.0 has a security risk. http://www.androidcentral.com/google-advises-developers-upgrade-android-studio-211-over-security-concerns

You should upgrade to the latest dev release (2.1.1) in the dev channel or if you are not in a hurry, the latest stable 1.5.2. in the stable channel. (Perhaps in the future, 1.5.2 will be available in the dev channel) The run button in 2.0 won't work, instant run will not always deploy changes.

Secondly I would not mix TV and mobile modules. It is advised to separate android TV and wear modules from mobile and tablet modules. Just create 2 separate apks.

[Any way to make common APK for API-15+ on mobile and API-21+ on TV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635700/any-way-to-make-common-apk-for-api-15-on-mobile-and-api-21-on-tv/35636253)

http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-5-2/